# Strange behavior using Tkinter Entry.get() with threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm been facing some strange issues trying to get tkinter (particularly the `Entry` class) to work with threads. I've narrowed the problem to the following sample:

```
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.root = Tk()
        self.field = Entry(self.root)
        self.field.insert(0,200)

        self.but = Button(text = 'get', command = Thread(target = self.getField,
                                                        args = self.field.get()
                                                        ).start)

        self.field.pack()
        self.but.pack()

    def getField(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            print (arg)
        return

myApp = App()
myApp.root.mainloop()
```

For some reason `self.field.get()` returns each digit in the entry field separately; I needed `*args` in `getField()` to discover this. When you press the button, the following is printed:

```
2
0
0
```

I expected `.get()` to return the whole field entry. Strangely, `.get()` also does not respond to new field entries, changing the value in the UI results in the same output.

The following code without threads works perfectly:

```
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.root = Tk()
        self.field = Entry(self.root)
        self.field.insert(0,200)

        self.but = Button(text = 'get', command = self.getField)

        self.field.pack()
        self.but.pack()

    def getField(self, *args):
        print(self.field.get())
        return

myApp = App()
myApp.root.mainloop()
```

What's wrong with my threaded code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code got it working for me:

```
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.root = Tk()
        self.field = Entry(self.root)
        self.field.insert(0,200)
        self.field.pack()
        self.but = Button(text = 'get', command = self.threadGetField) 
        self.but.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def threadGetField(self):
        my_thread = Thread(target=self.getField())
        my_thread.start()

    def getField(self):
        print(self.field.get())
        return

myApp = App()
```

It solved both problems - it shows the number in one line, because you only call the self.field.get() in the getField function, instead of as an arg. And it also shows me correct value even if I change the value, which did not work for me with the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed it works, but I'm curious why embedding the `.get()` method within `args` parameter caused the old value to be printed? I suspect its running `.get()` immediately upon `App` initialization, but that doesn't make sense since the thread starts only when you press the button.

Comment: @Darrel: it's because the call to `get()` was happening at the time the button was created, not the time it was clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread`'s arguments should be passed as tuples, as mentioned in the docs: *args is the argument tuple for the target invocation...*.
Making a tuple with its only item is `self.field.get()` makes your code work:

```
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.root = Tk()
        self.field = Entry(self.root)
        self.field.insert(0,200)

        self.but = Button(text = 'get', command = Thread(target = self.getField,
                                                        args = (self.field.get(), )
                                                        ).start)

        self.field.pack()
        self.but.pack()

    def getField(self, *args):
        print('>>>', args)
        for arg in args:
            print (arg)
        return

myApp = App()
myApp.root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
('>>>', ('200',))
200
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution resolves the returning as separate digits, but the output still ignores any new inputs to the field. Try changing the number to 999 in the UI and it still outputs 200.

Comment: This won't work in a real app because you're calling `self.fields.get()` about a millisecond after you've created the entry widget. The thread will always only have the initial value, not the value entered by the user.